# Fast way to Loop through date by groups

Tags: python, pandas, loops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkuQW.png)

I need to calculate the opening balance for an ID by using Ending balance of the last day.

I tried this code but to loop through each ID and each date. But it is too slow (I have 0.5Millions to deal with). Is there a better way to deal with this?

My thinking is my last 2 lines of code is not very efficient.

```
id_list = df['ID'].unique().tolist()
date_list = df['Date'].unique().tolist()

for t in id_list:
    k = 0
    for d in date_list:
        print(t,d)
        df.loc[(df['ID'] == t) & (dfx['Date'] == d), ['Opening Bal']] = k
        k = df.loc[(df['ID)'] == t) & (dfx['Date'] == d), ['Ending Bal']]
```

My thinking is my last 2 lines of code is not very efficient.

Comment: have a look at `groupby().shift()`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01/01/2023', '01/02/2023', '01/03/2023','01/01/2023', '01/02/2023', '01/03/2023'],
                   'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Ending Bal': [0.56, 0.73, 1.09, 0.34, 0.86, 1.83]})
df = df.sort_values(by=['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID'])
temp = []
for i in df['ID'].unique():
    temp = temp + [np.nan]+list(df[df['ID']==i]['Ending Bal'])[:-1]
df['Opening Bal'] = temp
```